# Title: Difficulty Displaying User Input Field on Ultimate Member Dashboard

Tags: wordpress

I'm seeking assistance with displaying user input fields on my Ultimate Member dashboard.

I've created a registration page with an input field for users to enter their department. However, I'm struggling to display each user's department on their respective dashboards. Despite trying various approaches, including utilizing Ultimate Member shortcodes, I haven't been successful.

Could someone please assist me with the correct shortcode or method to display the department input field value on the dashboard for each user?

I've attempted to display the text entered by a user in an input field using the Ultimate Member plugin, but I'm encountering issues.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!